# Is it possible to migrate Memcached cluster data to Redis?

Tags: memcached, redis

I have searched Google and SO and surprisingly haven't been able to find a very good answer to this.

Basically, I want to know if there is any sort of method or best practice for migrating cache data from a Memcached cluster into a Redis cluster.  Are there are any tools or tricks to help with this process?

If it's not possible, is there any recommendation for how to handle this?  I assume that pointing to a new cache that hasn't been pre-warmed will cause some application slowness, I'm just wondering if there are any workaround for this, assuming a migration of the Memcache data isn't possible.

Comment: It seems like you could do this yourself in about six lines of code.

Comment: How?  Can you elaborate?  I haven't found any examples, and don't work much with either of them.